# String parameter fetches null value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, function

I have this function that is supposed to take a file and remove any comments or blank lines from it, however, I can't test it because I can't get it to pass the argument into the function for some reason.

```
function Remove-Comments {
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$filePath

    Write-Output $filePath
    (Get-Content $filePath) | ForEach-Object { #Remove any comments that start the line or are lead by whitespace
        if($_ -like ' *#*') {
            $_ -replace ''
        }else{
            $_
        }
    } | Set-Content $filePath

    (Get-Content $filePath) | Where-Object {$_.trim() -ne ""} | Set-Content $filePath #Remove any lines that only include spaces
}
```

This is how I am calling the function:

```
Remove-Comments "C:\Users\#########\Desktop\Encryption Checker Datapack\data\custom_namespace\functions\load.mcfunction"
```

This is the file contents:

```
#
# load function
#

# load:
tellraw @a {"text":"Load function works!","color":"green"}

# function call:
execute if entity @a run function custom_namespace:check/function_call

# advancement:
advancement revoke @a only custom_namespace:this_is_an_advancement




#



# hella lines for test lol


# random command that doesn't do anythjing:
execute if block ~ ~ ~ air



# more dev notez
# more dev notez
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\########\Desktop\DatapackFileEncrypter.ps1:54 char:18
+     (Get-Content $filePath) | Where-Object {$_.trim() -ne ""} | Set-C ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your function definition is missing the `param(...)` block**:

```bash
function Remove-Comments {
  param(  # All parameter declaration must be inside this block.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$filePath
  )
  $filePath
  # ...
}
```

It is unfortunate that no syntax error is reported for your code, even though a `[Parameter()]` attribute clearly only makes sense in the context of a `param(...)` block.

- This problematic behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #10614](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10614).

As for **what happened** due to the missing `param(...)` block:

- Due to lack of a proper parameter declaration, your path argument passed on invocation did not bind to a parameter variable in your function.
- In effect, the `[Parameter()]` attribute was ignored and `[string] $filePath` became a *cast* from - undefined (in the context of the function) - variable `$filePath`. An undefined variable defaults to `$null`, and casting `$null` to `[string]` becomes the *empty string*, which your function implicitly outputs.
- `$filePath` - still undefined and therefore defaulting to `$null` - then caused `Get-Content` to report an error, because passing `$null` to the `-Path` parameter isn't allowed.